# How to use .firstWhereOrNull with Map?

Tags: dart, dictionary, extension-methods

I know someone already asked the same question. But i still confuse about something. I followed the provided answer and use this:

```
extension ExtendedMap on Map {
  /// The first entry satisfying test, or null if there are none.
  MapEntry? firstWhereOrNull(bool Function(MapEntry entry) test) {
    for (var entry in this.entries) {
      if (test(entry)) return entry;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

And i try:

```
someMap?.firstWhereOrNull((date) => (date > recentSunday )&& (date <= nextSunday)
```

But i got this error:

```
The operator '>' isn't defined for the type 'MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>'.Try defining the operator '>'.

The operator '<=' isn't defined for the type 'MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>'.Try defining the operator '<='.
```

I'm confused why this happened. I thought  it should work if any boolean function is passed as argument.Can anyone explain why it is asked to define the operator?

Comment: The argument to the callback is a [`MapEntry`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/MapEntry-class.html) object, which is a key-value *pair*, not just the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback has type `bool Function(MapEntry entry)`, so `date` is of type `MapEntry`. If you want to access the value associated with this entry, use `date.value`:

```dart
final result = someMap?.firstWhereOrNull((date) => (date.value > recentSunday )&& (date.value <= nextSunday));
                                                        ^^^^^^                         ^^^^^^
```

Complete example:

```dart
final someMap = {
  'halloween': 1,
  'christmas': 12,
  'easter': 123,
};

final recentSunday = 10;
final nextSunday = 30;

final result = someMap?.firstWhereOrNull((date) => (date.value > recentSunday )&& (date.value <= nextSunday));

print(result);
```

Console output:

```
MapEntry(christmas: 12)
```

Note that the returned value is also a `MapEntry`.